# How would I programatically login to a site such as codeproject or stackoverflow, using WebClient?

Tags: c#

I want to login to a site like stackoverflow or codeproject from a server.

Is there any way to login to a site such as this using the `WebClient` class?

Comment: Yes there is login link in SO. Use Firefox/IE/Chrome to login :-)

Comment: i think this question should go into meta.

Comment: @Oliver - why? Even the question as originally posted has no reason to go to meta...

Comment: though it seems meta-ish - the question is clearly about using a webclient to login to a service - doesn't that answer already exist on SO?

Comment: @Ata, if you're going to ask a question in which you use stackoverflow as an example, **be very careful how you do so**. There's an overriding urge, by some, to migrate any question that mentions stackoverflow to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, which wouldn't be the right place for it. Think about your wording and try to make clear in your question that it is **not** specific to stackoverflow and make even clearer **what the programming part of the question is** =)

Comment: I only used stackoverflow or codeproject as a sample !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/stackexchange-api/

### Update

1. Use Chrome Developer tools or Firebug in Firefox to look how the website in question posts the login data.
2. Copy the FORM data that chrome/firefox shows.
3. Create a `HttpWebRequest` and write the FORM data to `request.GetRequestStream()`
4. Set content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
5. Call `request.GetResponse()`.

Note that you got to keep all cookies which are specified in the response and copy them to all subsequent requests to keep being logged in.

Comment: this would only (potentially) help with half of the users question, but not the general case of "I want to login to a website programatically" which is what the OP alluded to by mentioning both stackoverflow and codeproject.. =)

Comment: definitely worthy of a +1. (BTW, the -1 wasn't me :)

Comment: i don't mind -1 as long as I get a motivation so that I can improve my answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do the same HTTP GET and POST request with `System.Net.WebClient`. But first you will have to check if the site allows login by programs. Mostly this is disallowed (that's why there a captchas!) and often there is a API to use instead of the normal web-interface!