# Youtube login using c#

Tags: c#

I want to login youtube using c#. I am using HttpWebRequest.
Procedure I am following:

1. load the login page using GET and parse GALX value
2. POST username/password along with GALX
3. get a meta refresh page, parse the url and load using GET
4. in every step cookies are handled using CookieContainer
5. UserAgent, ContentType etc header values are set and AllowAutoRedirect is true.

now i am getting the following Javascript code as response.

```
    var Ga, G = G || {};
    G.a = { g: "cookie_missing", f: "cookie_found", h: "gaia_failure" };
    var Gb = /\s*;\s*/;
    var Gc = function () {

        try 
        {
            return new XMLHttpRequest
        }
        catch (a) 
        {
            for (var b = ["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"], c = 0; c < b.length; c++)
                try 
                {
                    return new ActiveXObject(b[c])
                }
                catch (d) { }
        }

        return null
    },

    Gd = function () {

        this.d = Gc(); this.b = {}
    };
    Gd.prototype.oncomplete = function () { };

    Gd.prototype.send = function (a) {

        var b = [], c; 
        for (c in this.b) {
            var d = this.b[c];
            b.push(c + "=" + encodeURIComponent(d))
        }
        var b = b.join("&"), e = this.d, f = this.oncomplete;
        e.open("POST", a, !0);
        e.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        e.setRequestHeader("Content-length", "" + b.length);
        e.onreadystatechange = function () {
            4 == e.readyState && f({ status: e.status, text: e.responseText })
        };
        e.send(b)
    };
    Gd.prototype.get = function (a) {
        var b = this.oncomplete, c = this.d; c.open("GET", a, !0);
        c.onreadystatechange = function () { 4 == c.readyState && b({ status: c.status, text: c.responseText }) };
        c.send()
    };
    var Gf = function (a) {
        this.c = a; this.i = this.j();
        if (null == this.c) throw new Ge("Empty module name");
    };
    Ga = Gf.prototype;
    Ga.j = function () {
        var a = window.location.pathname;
        return a && 0 == a.indexOf("/accounts") ? "/accounts/JsRemoteLog" : "/JsRemoteLog"
    };
    Ga.k = function (a, b, c) {
        for (var d = this.i, e = this.c || "", d = d + "?module=" + encodeURIComponent(e), a = a || "", d = d + "&type=" + encodeURIComponent(a), b = b || "", d = d + "&msg=" + encodeURIComponent(b), c = c || [], a = 0; a < c.length; a++) d = d + "&arg=" + encodeURIComponent(c[a]);
        try {
            var f = Math.floor(1E4 * Math.random()), d = d + "&r=" + ("" + f)
        }
        catch (g) { }
        return d
    };
    Ga.send = function (a, b, c) {
        var d = new Gd; d.b = {};
        try {
            var e = this.k(a, b, c);
            d.get(e)
        } catch (f) { }
    };
    Ga.error = function (a, b) {
        this.send("ERROR", a, b)
    };
    Ga.warn = function (a, b) {
        this.send("WARN", a, b)
    };
    Ga.info = function (a, b) {
        this.send("INFO", a, b)
    };
    Ga.m = function (a) {
        var b = this;
        return function () {
            try {
                return a.apply(null, arguments)
            }
            catch (c) {
                throw b.error("Uncatched exception: " + c), c;
            }
        }
    };

    var Ge = function () { };
    G = G || {};
    G.e = G.e || new Gf("report_sid_status");
    G.l = function (a, b, c) {
        if (window.postMessage && window.parent) {
            if (a) {
                a:
                {
                    if (document.cookie)
                        for (var a = b + "=", b = document.cookie.split(Gb), d = 0; d < b.length; d++) {
                            var e = b[d], e = e.replace(/^\s+/, ""), e = e.replace(/\s+$/, "");
                            if (0 == e.indexOf(a)) {
                                a = e.substr(a.length);
                                break a
                            }
                        }
                    a = null
                }
                a = null == a ? G.a.g : G.a.f
            }
            else a = G.a.h; window.parent.postMessage(a, c)
        }
    };

    G_checkSidAndReport = G.e.m(G.l);

    G_checkSidAndReport('0', 'SID', 'https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com');
```

what to do now? Using this procedure I can successfully login Gmail but not youtube. I think javascript is posting to the server but I am unable to figure out actually what is posting.

Comment: This kind of question has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336395/login-using-webclient-or-httpwebrequest) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069302/how-would-i-programatically-login-to-a-site-such-as-codeproject-or-stackoverflow) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507855/c-sharp-login-examples) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336310/login-to-web-page-using-c-sharp).

Comment: please read the question again!

Answer (score 1):

I am at the same possition in my code from php, if you manage to figure it out please let me know. I think the key is in the following function with these parametters.

```
G.l=function(a='1',b='SID',c='https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com'){
if(window.postMessage&&window.parent){
    if(a){
        a:{
            if(document.cookie)for(var a=b+"=",b=document.cookie.split(Gb),d=0;
            d&lt;
            b.length;
            d++){
                var e=b[d],e=e.replace(/^\s+/,""),e=e.replace(/\s+$/,"");
                if(0==e.indexOf(a)){
                    a=e.substr(a.length);
                    break a
                }

            }
            a=null
        }
        a=null==a?G.a.g:G.a.f
    }
    else a=G.a.h;
    window.parent.postMessage(a,c)
}
```

}

Comment: Nop that is just a trim function fro the sid cookie.